# Firebase reads going rapidly up even when not doing anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, deployment, backend

To describe my problem in detail,

I started working on my first bigger project (a project management app) in React and till now it was going pretty well but after i started working on adding tasks to a project and updating graphs with the data the reads started going rapidly up and I can barely even continue working on it (literally I reach my free quota in 30 minutes).

Heres the code ive been working on that seems to have started the issue, first I thought that I created an infinite loop somewhere in the code that caused the reads to be so high yeasterday but I checked the code and it doesnt seem like it.

**//This is the parent which rerenderes when: a new task is added, a task is deleted, a tasks state is changed**

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log("fetching tasks");
        fetchTasks();
        //eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [showAddTask, deleteTitle, rerender])
```

**This is the child 'TaskCard', they are being rendered in the parent in a list**

```
const setTaskState = async () => {
        const task = await getDoc(currentTaskRef)
        if(task.data().state === 'incomplete'){
            await updateDoc(currentTaskRef, {state: 'complete'})
        }else{
            await updateDoc(currentTaskRef, {state: 'incomplete'})
        }
        setRerender(!rerender)
}
```

setTaskState inverts the tasks state (complete/incomplete) when clicked and causes the parent (the list where the task is in) to rerender and get the new updated sorted data again

The database structure goes like this:

[image: db structure]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be causing the issue?

I tried redoing the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Im even logging out the reads when I read something and they indicate that there is no infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was, turns out I created an infinite loop after all. If anyone new to backend like me is reading this, be carefull with useEffects and always console log your reads first to be 100% sure that everything is aight haha